# Error variable length column ROWID overflow FireDAC con tablas de tipo IOT Oracle

Tags: delphi, oracle-19c

Estoy trabajando con una versión XE7 de Delphi con conexión a Oracle que contiene tablas de tipo IOT, al realizar la activación de mis tablas que son 2931 y posteriormente realizar un First obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Variable length column ROWID overflow. Value length -24, column maximum length 23
```

Investigando en internet he encontrado que el valor de ROWID para las tablas de tipo IOT es más grande porque contiene el número de archivos de datos, numero de bloque y numero de fila, en el código llegue a la unidad FireDAC.Phys.OracleCli que contiene la constante IRowIdLen que tiene un valor de 23, justo el valor maximo que me esta devolviendo el error, probé aumentando este valor a 24 y he saltado el error, pero también probé con un valor de 25 y volví a obtener el error, probé con 26 y ya no salió el error, seguí probando con números consecutivos y curiosamente cuando el valor de la constante es par no obtengo el error pero cuando es impar si, mi pregunta es:

¿Cuál es el mejor valor a colocar a esta constante para ya no volver a obtener el error mencionado?

Comment: No tengo XE7 a mano, viendo en versiones posteriores, no existe la constante que referencias, existe otra, llamada`C_RowIdLen`, declarada en la unidad `FireDAC.Phys.OracleWrapper`. Es difícil decir si ha sufrido un renombrado o reingeniería, sin tener acceso al historial del código, pero viendo como se utiliza esta variable que yo veo, no debiera cambiarse su tamaño, pues hay estructuras, buffers, que se pasan a la OCI, cuyo tamaño depende de ese valor. Por ejemplo, la rutina `TOCIStatement.GetRowId` asigna un buffer del tamaño de esa variable.

Comment: He buscado la constante que mencionas y no la tengo, supongo que si fue renombrada porque la que yo te menciono se hace su llamado en la misma unidad que me mencionas (FireDAC.Phys.OracleWrapper) , accedí a su valor desde esta y ya fue que llegue a la unidad FireDAC.Phys.OracleCli, si mencionas que este valor no se debe de cambiar, ¿qué es lo que me recomiendas hacer para corregir el error?

Comment: Valide en la versión Rio y Sidney de Delphi y veo que ahí si se ocupa para otras cuestiones como los buffers que mencionas, tuviste manera de probar en tu delphi si este error te aparecia?, en XE7 esta constante solo se utiliza en la unidad FireDAC.Phys.OracleWrapper con IRowIdLen * SizeOf(TFDAnsiChar), que veo en el código de Sidney y Rio que también esta

Comment: No, lo que te respondo es de pura memoria, concepto e investigación, porque no estoy trabajando actualmente con Oracle y no tengo una instancia a mano para hacer pruebas. Eventualmente podría instalar una instancia, quizás una XE, pero por ahora no dispongo del tiempo para ponerme a ello.

Comment: Ok, entiendo gracias